# How do I export a single layer as pdf in cadsoft eagle?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-layers

I want to export a single layer e.g. tPlace as a pdf vector graphic. The vector part is optional, is there any ULP that can help me do that?

If I can export it as png or tiff it would also be fine since I can convert them to pdf afterwards.

Comment: You just select that single layer only and print it using the pdf writer as a virtual output device. You don't need a ULP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eagle doesn't have a direct "print one layer" feature, however it is very simple to do.

1. First hide all layers but the one you want to print. The command to this is simply:

   `display none tPlace`

   Or any other layer for that matter. `None` will hide all layers, and then `tPlace` or other layer number/name will show just that layer.
2. Press print, select your settings, and choose "Print to File (PDF)". Your visible layer is now printed. If you want the print output to be solid black rather than its default layer colour, you can select the "Black" option.
3. To return the displayed layers back to how they were:

   `display last`

   That will reset the visible layers to what they were before you ran the command in step 1.

The resulting PDF file is a Vector graphic as you have requested.

If you prefer not to enter commands, you can achieve the same thing using the "display" button (top left just below the `i` button). For step 1, click that button, then click None, and then select your layer. For step 3, right click on the display button and select "Last".

Comment: Done and done, much obliged!

Comment: @MattCox If this answered your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the tick mark under the vote tally.